# GIMP: A code to edit a whole folder of images

Tags: gimp, images, image-editing, script, python

*[GIMP 2.8.16]*

---

**EDITED: See below.**

Hi,

I am new to python, and I need to ask the community to please help me find where is this code failing. I am having trouble. This is version 1.0, following [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/53965/100562):

```
import glob
source_folder = "/home/pecesaquadros/Desktop/T/"
dest_folder = "/home/pecesaquadros/Desktop/T2/"

def auto(source_folder, dest_folder):
    for filename in glob(source_folder  + "/*.JPG"):
        img = pdb.gimp_file_load(source_folder + filename, source_folder + filename)
        pdb.gimp_image_rotate(img,0)
        pdb.gimp_image_convert_grayscale(img)
        drawable = pdb.gimp_image_get_active_drawable(img)
        pdb.gimp_brightness_contrast(drawable, 28,100)
        disp = pdb.gimp_display_new(img)
        yield img
        pdb.gimp_image_merge_visible_layers(img, CLIP_TO_IMAGE)
        pdb.gimp_file_save(img, img.layers[0], dest_folder + filename, dest_folder + filename)
        pdb.gimp_display_delete(disp)
        pdb.gimp_image_delete(img)  # drops the image from gimp memory

seq = auto(source_folder, dest_folder)
next(seq)
```

with output, in *GIMP 2.8.16 Python Console*:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 2, in auto
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Many thanks. I am sure this question will help many. I might make a plugin out of it, with interesting parameters, available for everybody; it will be named "Photocopy" :)

...next I am creating a loop to create a TeX code that will compile all images to a pdf...

Thanks again,

Al

---

**EDIT**

New code:

```
import glob
source_folder = "/home/pecesaquadros/Desktop/T/"
dest_folder = "/home/pecesaquadros/Desktop/T2/"

def auto(source_folder, dest_folder):
    for filename in glob.glob(source_folder  + "/*.JPG"): #blabla.JPG
        img = pdb.gimp_file_load(filename,filename)
        pdb.gimp_image_rotate(img,0)              #Editing starts
        pdb.gimp_image_convert_grayscale(img)
        pdb.gimp_image_select_rectangle(img, 2, 0, 0, 1839, 600)
        drawable = pdb.gimp_image_get_active_drawable(img)
        pdb.gimp_brightness_contrast(drawable, 60,127)
        pdb.gimp_image_select_rectangle(img, 2, 0, 600, 1839, 900)
        drawable = pdb.gimp_image_get_active_drawable(img)
        pdb.gimp_brightness_contrast(drawable, 32,127)
        pdb.gimp_image_select_rectangle(img, 2, 0, 1500, 1839, 900)
        drawable = pdb.gimp_image_get_active_drawable(img)
        pdb.gimp_brightness_contrast(drawable, 14,127)
        pdb.gimp_image_select_rectangle(img, 2, 0, 2400, 1839, 900)
        drawable = pdb.gimp_image_get_active_drawable(img)
        pdb.gimp_brightness_contrast(drawable, 0,127)
        disp = pdb.gimp_display_new(img)      #Editing ends
        yield img               #Image is displayed for me to manipulate
        pdb.gimp_image_merge_visible_layers(img, CLIP_TO_IMAGE)
        pdb.gimp_file_save(img, img.layers[0],filename,dest_folder + filename)
        pdb.gimp_display_delete(disp)
        pdb.gimp_image_delete(img)

seq = auto(source_folder, dest_folder)
next(seq) #This, and enter, to go to the next file
```

Results in:

1. Files are overwritten, not saved in the new folder
2. Sometimes, and only sometimes, one of these two errors appear:

**A**

[image: GIMP Message]

**B**

[image: GIMP Message]

0_0

PS: *yield* is in my plans.

Comment: you should be aware the code you copied from sports the `yield` statement because that question had a requirement for manual intervention in each image. If all you want to do in the image is automated, you can drop the `yield` line, as well as the calls to  `pdb.gimp_display_new` and `pdb.gimp_display_delete` - and GIMP will process all your images as fast as possible.

Comment: I want yield to happen. Thank you jsbueno, and thank you for your email.

Comment: I can't get around with, as coded in your answer, `pdb.gimp_file_save(img, img.layers[0],dest_folder + filename,dest_folder + filename)`. Output is _RuntimeError: Could not open '/home/pecesaquadros/Desktop/T2//home/pecesaquadros/Desktop/T‌​2/P1050289.JPG' for reading: No such file or directory_. I have fiddled around with it. For instance,`pdb.gimp_file_save(img, img.layers[0],filename,dest_folder + filename)` and `pdb.gimp_file_save(img, img.layers[0],filename,filename)` both let the program run but files are overwritten and not saved in dest_folder.

Answer (score 2):

`glob` is module that contains a `glob` function, so that shouldn't be `glob(source_folder  + "/*.JPG")` but `glob.glob(source_folder  + "/*.JPG")`

Also, if you give a path as part of the pattern to glob.glob(), the output will contain the full path to the files. Since you are re-adding the directory name to it, it  appears twice in the name you give to gimp_file_load(). So try something like:

```
for filename in glob.glob(source_folder  + "/*.JPG"):
    img = pdb.gimp_file_load(filename,filename)
```

Comment: Thank you. I've learned more than what I was expecting from such a concise answer. However, new output is:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 3, in auto
RuntimeError: Could not open '/home/pecesaquadros/Desktop/T//home/pecesaquadros/Desktop/T/P1050289.JPG' for reading: No such file or directory

Comment: See edited answer.

Comment: Thank you, xenoid. Same problem occurred with pdb.gimp_file_save(img, img.layers[0], dest_folder + filename, dest_folder + filename). After fixing both, see what happens... (see edited question).

Comment: Your code sort of works for me. Add print statements in your code (especially to show the value of img and img). Then you can see which statement is producing the error message and what is the value of img.ID when this happens.

Comment: I will investigate further. To finish with this and call it to an end (or to an _answer_), files are overwritten, not saved in the destination folder.

Comment: Time to RTFM. The doc of `gimp-display-delete` says: *This procedure removes the specified display. If this is the last remaining display for the underlying image, then the image is deleted also.* Since this applies to your case, the image is already deleted when you try to delete it with `gimp-image-delete`.

Comment: Time to RTQ: In my case, "sometimes, and only sometimes, one of these two errors appear", whatever the folder whatever the image whatever I do. Furthermore, I stated: "I will investigate further". The topic now was about files being overwritten. Thank you for your last unhelpful and unnecessary vulgar comment.

Comment: *about getting files saved at dest_folder (and I know the actual code gives instructions to overwrite)